# Manage http error codes with Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I wrote:

```
private RequestBuilder getPostRequest(String api) {
        return Rest.post(url + api)
                .jsonContent()
                .header("wsc-access-key", WowzaAccount.getAccessKey())
                .header("wsc-api-key", WowzaAccount.getRestKey());
    }
```

```
getPostRequest("live_streams").body(json).fetchAsJsonMap(new OnComplete<Response<Map>>() {
            @Override
            public void completed(Response<Map> v) {
                if (v.getResponseCode() == 201) {
                    // success
                    Map<String, Object> response = v.getResponseData();
                    name = (String) response.get("name");
                    id = (String) response.get("id");
                    connection_code = (String) response.get("connection_code");
                    Log.p("WowzaLiveStream -> (Code 201) Successfully created live stream with name " + name, Log.DEBUG);
                    onComplete.completed(instance);
                } else if (v.getResponseCode() == 401) {
                    Log.p("WowzaLiveStream -> (Code 401) Unauthorized, failed to create live stream with name " + params.name.get(), Log.DEBUG);
                    onFail.run();
                } else if (v.getResponseCode() == 422) {
                    Log.p("WowzaLiveStream -> (Code 422) Unprocessable Entity, failed to create live stream with name " + params.name.get(), Log.DEBUG);
                    onFail.run();
                } else {
                    Log.p("WowzaLiveStream -> Unknow response with code " + v.getResponseCode() + ", failed to create live stream with name " + params.name.get(), Log.DEBUG);
                    onFail.run();
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem is that when I get a 422 response code my `onFail` callback is not called. Instead a `Dialog` appears. I suppose that this dialog is invoked by the default `addNetworkErrorListener` code in the `init()`. However... I cannot (and I don't want to) disable the default `addNetworkErrorListener` code, because I'm writing a new CN1Lib. Instead I need that in this case, and only in this case, the network error listener should not be invoked and instead the failure callback that I wrote should be run.

It's more appropriate, in this case, to call the network error listener only if the Internet connection is lost.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly catch the error code callback as the callback might have a different format than the main JSON:

```
private RequestBuilder getPostRequest(String api) {
    return Rest.post(url + api)
            .jsonContent()
            .header("wsc-access-key", WowzaAccount.getAccessKey())
            .header("wsc-api-key", WowzaAccount.getRestKey())
            .onErrorCodeJSON(map -> { 
               // process error response
            });

}
```

Comment: Thank you Shai, I fixed my code according to the your blog article https://www.codenameone.com/blog/rest-api-error-handling.html, and now I can manage correctly each error code.